# creating keytab to automate scripts

Tags: bash, kerberos, keytab

I am having trouble creating a `keytab` in order to automate the script I am running.

I am using this website for reference [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aumh)

This is what I did so far:

```
$ ktutil
ktutil:  addent -password -p bli1@testtesttest.corp.supernice.net -k 1 -e arcfour-hmac
Password for bli1@testtesttest.corp.supernice.net: 
ktutil:  
ktutil:  wkt bli1.keytab
ktutil:  quit
```

When I tried to run the script, I got this error:

```
$ kinit bli1@testtesttest.corp.supernice.net -k -t bli1.keytab; python3 -m pytrinity.monitors.rate_monitor test
kinit: Cannot find KDC for requested realm while getting initial credentials
```

I'm not sure if I created the `keytab` correctly as I am having a hard time finding in-depth documentation on each argument during the `keytab` creation process. I'm not sure what `-k` is used for.

```
addent: add entry
-password: add password
-p: principal
-e: encryption
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with connectivity to your KDC as per error message. What's in your kerberos configuration file? /etc/krb5.conf is usually the name for it.

Comment: You need to look at what kdc hostname/address is for your realm. Then try ping to see if  you can reach it from the box.

Comment: I cant change anything in krb6.conf as I do not have permissions and cannot change these permissions. In my `[realm]` `CORP.COMPANY.NET ={kdc = qycdccorp01.corp.company.net}` I tried `ping qycdccorp01.corp.company.net` from the box and was able to get responses

Comment: Then go ahead and try to do kinit using your generated keytab with `kinit -k -t <keytab_file> bli1@testtesttest.corp.supernice.net` and see if it's successful or not. But let me tell you one thing, usually when you specify realm you do it in all capital letters. So try this one first, if it doesn't work then specify @TESTxxxxx all in capitals